# How to apply css based on the content of the html tag using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have created a table using ngFor and so does not have explicitly defined tags.

```
<tr *ngFor = "let row of food;">
        <td *ngFor ="let col of headers;">
            {{row[col]}}
        </td>
</tr>
```

I have selected a column using: (css)

```
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

it selects all the cells in the 2nd column.

I want to change the color of the cells of nd column based on the content of the cells using css only. Please do answer even if it isn't necessarily possible using css.

Comment: What HTML does that Angular script produce to go in your DOM? As yet there is no means to style an element based on its content (with a few exceptions, such as `:focus-within`), but if the content is placed in an attribute of the element that might be possible. But it depends on what styling you want, what colour should map to what content?

Comment: CSS does not have conditionals in sense of programming. You would have to do with javascript, by setting a specific class or CSS directly.

Comment: You'll need to add CSS classes conditionally within your td tag, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that in Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the dummy example:

**HTML:**

```
<p-table
  paginatorDropdownAppendTo="body"
  #dataTable
  [value]=""
  [paginator]="true"
  [rows]="10"
  [(first)]="first"
  [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 20, 30, 50, 100]" >
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-i="rowIndex" let-ord>
    <tr>
      <td
       style="text-align:center"
        [class]="'orderstatus_' + ord.Point_Order_Status_ID" >
       {{ ord.Status_Name }}
      </td>
    </tr>
 </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .theme_table{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    font-size: 13px;

  thead {
     background: var(--theme-heading-gradient);
     text-transform: uppercase;
     background-color: var(--theme-box-heading-color);
  }

  th {
    padding: 15px 15px;
  }

 td {
    background: #121b35;

   &.orderstatus_1 {
     background: #ffc107 !important;
     color: black;
   }

   &.orderstatus_2 {
     background: #ff7e00 !important;
   }

   &.orderstatus_3 {
     background: #34ce7f !important;
   }

   &.orderstatus_4 {
      background: #d32f2f !important;
   }
 }

 tbody {
     td:first-child {
     border-left: 5px solid var(--theme-background-color);
     border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  }

   td:last-child {
     border-right: 5px solid var(--theme-background-color);
     border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
   }

   tr:nth-child(even) td {
     background: #172242;
   }

   tr:last-child td {
     border-bottom: 4px solid var(--theme-background-color);
   }
  }
}
```